# Looks like there's nothing for it but the lake

Tags: meaning

Looks like there's nothing for it but the lake.
(A sentence in the novel of "A Burglar's Christmans by Willa Cather)

Comment: Hard to know without the context, but it probably means something like, “It appears we have no choice but (to go into? to choose?) the lake”.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We appreciate added information about your question, for example, what is it exactly? I presume you're asking, what does "there's nothing in it but..." mean. What do you think? What do you find confusing? Without more information, this is likely to be closed as being too confusing.

Comment: @Susan, 'too confusing' is not an option comprised among SE closing reasons, yet, but I think it would be helpful to include that, too.

Answer (score 3):

The context of the story is "two very shabby looking young men" standing on the corner of a snowy, muddy, slushy street in Chicago on Christmas Eve. Passing vehicles throw freezing slop on them, and they have the following exchange:

> "Well," remarked the elder of the two, "I guess we are at our rope's end, sure enough. How do you feel?"
>
> "Pretty shaky. The wind's sharp tonight. If I had had anything to eat I mightn't mind it so much. There is simply no show. I'm sick of the whole business. Looks like there's nothing for it but the lake."
>
> "O, nonsense, I thought you had more grit. Got anything left you can hock?"

The simplest interpretation of the younger man's observation that "there's nothing for it but the lake" (that is, Lake Michigan) is that he's suggesting that the two should drown themselves. You certainly wouldn't take a dip in Lake Michigan on Christmas Eve just to clean muddy slush off your clothes.